# how to process an upload file in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a simple Flask app and I would like for it to process an uploaded excel file and display it's data in the webpage.  So far I got a page to upload the excel file.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, DOCUMENTS, IMAGES

app = Flask(__name__)

#the name 'datafiles' must match in app.config to DATAFILES
docs = UploadSet('datafiles', DOCUMENTS)
app.config['UPLOADED_DATAFILES_DEST'] = 'static/uploads'
configure_uploads(app, docs)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index():
  # return send_file("templates/index.html")
  return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/upload", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
  #user_file is the name value in input element
  if request.method == 'POST' and 'user_file' in request.files:
    filename = docs.save(request.files['user_file'])
    return filename
  return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/mergedata", methods=['GET'])
def merge_data():
   return send_file("templates/mergeDataPage.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data action ="{{url_for('upload')}}">
      <input type="file" name="user_file">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Once the file is uploaded, I would like to process this excel data by using another python script - This script will take the excel file, remove special characters and converted to a csv file/output.  I would like to display the csv output in the webpage.

The idea is for users to upload the file, press a button to clean the data and have the results printed in an output box.  How do I go about in building something like this scenario?

I'm pretty new to Flask, but so far has been pretty exciting to learn this cool web framework. Your help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @vishes_shell since I'm new to Flask, just figured out how to upload a file, set the routes and built a script in pandas to convert the file into a csv - first time using pandas.  I hope you didn't get the idea that I'm just looking for the answer, I just need some directions on how to process the data, perhaps from the `main.py` and display the results in the current page. Maybe some tutorials will be helpful.  Also I was thinking of making the pandas script as a class, call it from the `main.py`, and deliver it as a json.  My background is in front end dev so little backend exposure.

Comment: if you saved a file, you have script that convert that file to a data that you can easily render, you are probably done, you just need to do all those things in your upload view(after saving the file) and then after all render template with that data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module and first convert the excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
data_xls = pd.read_excel('your_workbook.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
data_xls.to_csv('your_csv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Pandas is spectacular for dealing with csv files, and the following code would be all you need to read a csv and save an entire column into a variable:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
saved_column = df.column_name #you can also use df['column_name']
```

For instance if you wanted to save all of the info in your column Names into a variable, this is all you need to do:

```
names = df.Names
```

Comment: @Gowda pandas is what I'm using for the script that will take excel file and converted to csv.  Question how to use that script from main.py, process it, and display the results, in this case the variable, in a different page or current page.  Not familiar with Flask

Comment: you don't need to have 2 different script files for it. You can do the uploading, conversion and output all in the same script.